# Why does adding Date doesnt work but subtract date works? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm adding 1 Week on `this.currentDate`. Problem: `subWeek()` is working but `addWeek()` doesnt work.

Every other operator except '+' is working.

this is my vue.js component:

```
<template>
<div>
...
 <button @click="addWeek()">test
 <button @click="subWeek()">test
...
</div>
</template>
```

...

```
 methods: {

    addWeek(){
      showAjaxLoading(true);
      this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate()  + 6));
      console.log(this.currentDate);
      showAjaxLoading(false);
    },
    subWeek(){
      showAjaxLoading(true);
      this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() - 6));
      showAjaxLoading(false);
    },
},
created() {
    this.currentDate = new Date();
},
 data(){
    return {
      currentDate : null,

    }
  },
```

### **Excpected output:**

window output: this.currentDate : 2021-07-21

*after button click on addWeek:*

window output: this.currentdate : 2021-07-28

### **Real output:**

window output: this.currentDate : 2021-07-21

*after button click on addWeek:*

window output: this.currentdate : 2021-07-21

**console.log output: 2021-07-28**

*after second button click on addWeek:*

**window output: this.currentdate : 2021-07-21**

**console.log output: 2021-07-28**

Comment: Can you describe what result you are seeing vs what you expected to see?

Comment: May I ask you why you do `this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() + 6));` instead of simply doing `this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() + 6)`? (Or, even better `+ 7`, if you want to add a week ;) )

Comment: @secan if i do it like you it is not a date object it is a unix number

Comment: Is that some kind of specific behavior of Vue.js? Because in "vanilla" JavaScript `this.currentDate` is not converted into a number (example here: https://jsfiddle.net/djzx8my2/)